Transactional Rollback for Messages with X-Death Header
I have a Spring AMQP configuration with transaction management enabled that hits a scenario where the necessary rollbacks are not occurring in my listener.
My exchange configuration is as follows:

status - DirectExchange with dead-letter to status.dlx
status.dlx - DirectExchange with time-to-live and dead-letter to status
status.plx - DirectExchange for messages to be routed to parking-lot

Additionally, I have a ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler configured along with an exception handler so that messages that contain an x-death header are discarded. When this occurs, I use the handleDiscarded(Message failed) hook to send the message to our parking lot exchange (status.plx).
The messaging pattern in the event of an exception in this case is:
status -> listener encounters exception -> status.dlx -> status -> listener encounters exception with x-death -> handleDiscarded -> status.plx
This flow was preferred due to this snippet from the Spring AMQP Exception Handling documentation:

A common pattern for handling DLQ messages is to set a time-to-live on those messages as well as additional DLQ configuration such that these messages expire and are routed back to the main queue for retry. The problem with this technique is that messages that cause fatal exceptions loop forever. Starting with version 2.1, the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler detects an x-death header on a message that causes a fatal exception to be thrown. The message is logged and discarded. You can revert to the previous behavior by setting the discardFatalsWithXDeath property on the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler to false.

This is all working as expected, however, I've discovered that my listener does not rollback transactions when the message is discarded in this manner.
This appears to be due to the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError implementation, which throws an ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException when an x-death header is present:
/**
 * Special exception for listener implementations that want to signal that the current
 * batch of messages should be acknowledged immediately (i.e. as soon as possible) without
 * rollback, and without consuming any more messages within the current transaction.
 *
 * @author Dave Syer
 * @author Gary Russell
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException extends AmqpException {
    /* omitted */
}

As a result of this, the first time my listener fails and routes to dead-letter, my database processing within the listener is rolled back. Then, the second time my listener fails with x-death and discards the message, my listener will not roll back transactions despite encountering an exception / ultimately routing to parking-lot.
Ideally, I want my listener to always roll back if an exception is encountered.
I'm wondering if there's any type of flag I can set to accomplish this, or if my configuration should be changed. Ideally I wanted to leverage the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleDiscarded so that all of my routing was handled through configuration as opposed to setting up listeners or manually checking x-death.
Is there any way I can leverage the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler and ensure that a rollback occurs in the event of an x-death header?
If I'm unable to do this, I was considering dead-lettering to parking lot immediately instead of letting the retries ultimately do this for me, but I'm not sure if that's a recommended approach.
I'm currently configured with spring-boot 2.5.2 / spring-amqp 2.3.9 and my transaction manager is a JpaTransactionManager

According to the ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException logic, the consumer execution has to finish normally, so we can catch that exception and call this.channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, true); to remove such a message from original queue.
I wonder if you can try for your use-case in the handleDiscarded() to do this:
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

This way your JPA transaction will be marked for rollback.
Not sure, though, how an AMQP client would react for that...

Thank you for your reply. When I tried to set the transaction status in my handleDiscarded(), this results in a NoTransactionException, at which point we hit a loop where our listener fires again (with x-death 1) and we ultimately encounter the same exception:
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(TransactionAspectSupport.java:159) at MMMessaging$2.handleDiscarded(MMMessaging.java:181)


I'm currently exploring other hooks to set rollback only (i.e. in handleError) but it seems like it will always result in a consumer restart / listener firing again.

So, apparently the listener container is not a part of the transaction. Might be great if you can share with us a simple project where we can reproduce and play with.
